# $a$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $b$ is an eigenvalue of $B$, but $ab$ is not an eigenvalue of $AB$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm asked this weird problem (I'll do my best to completely translate it):

Find what's wrong with the following train of thought:

"If $a \in \mathbb{K}$ is an eigenvalue of $A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{K})$ and $b \in \mathbb{K}$ is an eigenvalue of $B \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{K})$ then $ab$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$. In fact, if there is an $X \in M_{n \times 1}$ such that $X \neq 0$ and $BX = bX$ then we have:" $$A(BX) = A(bX) = b(AX) = b(aX) = (ba)X = (ab)X$$

Now I think this is incorrect **JUST** because they didn't state that $X$ is also an eigenvector of $A$ associated with the eigenvalue $a$.

Otherwise, I think it makes sense... but I'm not sure...

Comment: You assumed that the **same** $X$ is eigenvector for both of your eigenvalues.

Comment: I didn't... actually, the fact they weren't explicit about that is my answer to the problem.

Comment: You need to correct your confusing usage of eigenvector and eigenvalues. $a$ is used simultaneously as eigenvalue and eigenvector.

Comment: @Zhanxiong you'r right, it was a mistake. Edited

Comment: @mozzarino Then first of all, does the notation "$ab$" make sense? I think it's more plausible that you meant $a$ and $b$ are eigenvalues. Take more time to make your title and content consistent.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I'm confused... Are you referring to the mistake of me saying that $a$ and $b$ being eigenvectors? They are eigenvalues, such as $ab$ is supposed to be the eigenvalue of $AB$

Comment: @mozzarino Yes. In your title, you stated "$a$ is an eigenvector of $A$...", which should be corrected.

Comment: @Zhanxiong corrected the title now, thanks for the warning. I didn't realize I made the same mistake twice.

Comment: Why do you replace $AX$ with $aX$?

Comment: It doesn’t make sense at all because you don’t know whether $A$ and $B$ will have a common eigenvector.. what is $X$ in the explanation? An eigenvecor of $A$ or an eigenvector of $B$? If it is both, you are assuming $A$ and $B$ have at least one common eigenvector(namely $X$), but they have no reason to have a common one.

Comment: It’s like saying: let x be a solution of 2x=3, and let x be a solution of 3x=4. Do you see what goes wrong?

Comment: @M.Van $X$ is said to be an eigenvector of $B$, but its not said to be an eigenvector of $A$... So I thought that was the error in the train of thought. This problem is kind of a "spot the mistake" problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is good. But to be more affirmative, all you need is a concrete counterexample. Consider
\begin{align*}
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}. \quad
\end{align*}
Then $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $2$ is an eigenvalue of $B$, but $2 = 1 \times 2$ is of course not an eigenvalue of $AB = 0$!

Comment: If they said that $X$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with $a$ and an eigenvector of $B$ associated with $b$, would $ab$ always be an eigenvalue of $AB$ with $X$ being an eigenvector of $AB$ associated to the eigenvalue $ab$?

Comment: @mozzarino Yes, that's correct. And the equation you put in the question is the proof to it.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense